# fastet way to calculate mean of each rgb channel of specific coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I've build a lot of functions for this purpose and the fastest one is:

```
meanRGB[:] = sum([img[i,j,:] for i,j in args])/len(args)
```

but this is still so slow for large images.
it takes like 40 seconds for a 4700x3100 image.(it's running on an old cpu(4th generation) but it doesn't really matter)

***args*** contains 2d coordinates of specific x,y

```
[[0 0] [1 0] [2 1] ...]
```

**UPDATE**

thanks to all of you kind guys who sent these great methods. I think joostblack's way is the fastest one.
here you can simulate the situation(shortened):

```
clusterMap = [[1,4,2],[1,2,3],[3,1,4]]
np.random.seed(2)
img = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 255, size = (4700, 3100, 3))
segments = np.unique(clusterMap)

meanRGB = np.zeros((len(segments),3))

for k, segment in enumerate(segments.ravel()):
    args = np.argwhere(clusterMap==segment)
    meanRGB[k,:] = sum([img[i,j,:] for i,j in args])/len(args)

    
print(f"\n{meanRGB}")
```

Comment: how long is `args`?

Comment: @joostblack depends on image. it's like 1/10 of dimension of image (10 coordinates for a 10x10 image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a shot. I think this is faster but I do not have your image or your `args` array so I am not sure.

```
import numpy as np

# Trying to recreate your situation
img = np.random.rand(4700,3100,3)
args = np.array([[2,3],[0,1],[2,4],[5,5]])

# my attempt
meanRGB = np.mean(img[args[:,0],args[:,1],:],axis=0)
print(meanRGB)
```

(example) output:

```
[0.68078292 0.4485302  0.46863616]
```

Comment: perfect. that is about 6x faster! thank you

Comment: @joostblack what does mean `args = np.array([[2,3],[0,1],[2,4],[5,5]])
` ?

Comment: @FreddyDaniel I tried to recreate the `args` array to show my function works. You do not need this in your code but it functions as mock data.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `numba`:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (4700, 3100, 3))
args = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (100000, 2))

@njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def average(array, indices):
    n = len(indices)
    sum_ = np.zeros(3)
    for i in prange(n):
        sum_ += array[indices[i][0], indices[i][1], :]
    return sum_/n
```

Validation:

```
op = sum(img[i,j,:] for i,j in args)/len(args)
numba_ = average(img, args) 
np.isclose(op, numba_)

# array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Benchmark (it's about few hundred times faster):

```
%%timeit
meanRGB = sum(img[i,j,:] for i,j in args)/len(args)

# 124 ms ± 704 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit average(img, args)

# 136 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you. it was really faster than my code(13.85 seconds) but it was still slower than @joostblack

Comment: @Abolfazl74 Please note that the first run right after creating function will be lot slower than the runs after since `numba` needs to compile the function.

Comment: There is further potential to speed up the method a bit (more than 2x). You can give the compiler more information about the memory layout of the arrays by `assert array.shape[2]  ==3` and `assert indices.shape[1]==2` and you can use 3 scalar values for calculating the sum.

Answer (score 2):

split by channels and then use the builtin mean

```
r = np.mean(img[:,:,0])
g = np.mean(img[:,:,1])
b = np.mean(img[:,:,2])
```

if your list is not the full image youd want to mask it using

```
mask = np.zeros_like(test[:,:,0])
x_coords = [c[0] for c in args]
y_coords = [c[1] for c in args]
mask[x_coords,y_coords] = 1
r = np.mean(test[mask==1][:,0])
g = np.mean(test[mask==1][:,1])
b = np.mean(test[mask==1][:,2])
```

Comment: I mean that's a cool way but it's not still faster. thank you anyway.

Comment: @Abolfazl74 for an admittedly somewhat smaller image (500x900) it goes through almost instantaneos for me

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following manner:

```
red_channel_mean = img[:, :, 0].mean()

green_channel_mean = img[:, :, 1].mean()

blue_channel_mean = img[:, :, 2].mean()
```

Cheers

Comment: thank you but thats about 3x slower than my code! and needed some corrections  : red_channel_mean = 0
    green_channel_mean = 0
    blue_channel_mean = 0

    for i,j in args:
        red_channel_mean += img[i, j, 0]
        green_channel_mean += img[i, j, 1]
        blue_channel_mean += img[i, j, 2]
        
    meanRGB[:] = [red_channel_mean/len(args), green_channel_mean/len(args), blue_channel_mean/len(args)]

Comment: It makes no sense, as `numpy` methods are optimized and usually run substantially faster than any code you can write. I really don't know what kind of image did you use, but I've applied your code on an image of shape `(3024, 4032, 3)` and it ran 19.08 `seconds`, as opposed to 0.03 `seconds` for my code. Can you please provide an example where you can present your statement ?

Comment: I can give you a proof using an email or something but there is something that you didn't consider tho. this code is using in a complex situation with other variables and it iterates over about 100 times(that's why I couldn't give y'all a good code to simulate the situation)! so the result might be different for you. I noticed your code is working quite good but in this example, it is still slower than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the indices together, mask the input and compute the mean:

```
>>> img[tuple(zip(*args))].mean(0)
```

For instance, given `args` as:

```
>>> args
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [1, 4], [0, 2]]

>>> tuple(zip(*args))
((1, 2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 4, 2))
```

Comment: thank you. it's faster than my way(27.40043544769287 seconds) but not faster than @joostblack 's way

Comment: It's roughly the same method, maybe the `zip` is taking a little longer with a larger `args`.